# Uniform Convergence of $(x + \frac{1}{n})^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show that $f_n(x) = (x + \frac{1}{n})^2$ converges uniformly. So $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x + \frac{1}{n})^2 = (\lim_{n \to \infty} (x + \frac{1}{n}))^2 = x^2$.

I want to show that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for $n$ large enough. So

$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = |(x + \frac{1}{n})^2 - x^2| = |x^2 + \frac{2x}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} - x^2| = |\frac{2xn}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}|$

**Edit** Uniform convergence does not occur on $\mathbb{R}$. But let me consider the interval $[-5, 5]$. Since $x \in [-5, 5]$, $|\frac{2xn}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}| < |\frac{10n}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}|$, which will be made less than $\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Are the functions defined on an interval or in the entire $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @matgaio: They are defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it will $|\frac{2x}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}|$

Comment: yes.So you are trying to do from the definition?Wertrass M test is also derived from the definiton.

Comment: well I was wrong, the sereis does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$ only converges point wise

Comment: @matgaio: I'm not aware of it. I'll be on the look out for it.

Comment: @matgaio, that is not correct: consider $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, sorry. This is the classical example, indeed. You are right Santiago. I was thinking on another thing. Sorry mainly for @Student. I erased that. Thanks a lot for pointing that. Silly me, hehe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this sequence doesn't converge uniformly to $f(x)=x^2$. We need to prove that: given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_\epsilon$ such that $n>n_\epsilon$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. But

$$\left|\frac{2xn}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}\right|=\left|\frac{2xn-1}{n^2}\right|$$

and, for a fized $n$, this is less than $\epsilon$ for all $x$ if and only if

$$|2xn-1|\leqslant n^2\epsilon$$

wich is false, because $x$ can be large enough to make the left side greater than the right.

Comment: So what would $(x + \frac{1}{n})^2$ converge to?

Comment: @Student it converges to $x^2$, but the convergence is _not_ uniform on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Could you formulate again the question on this comment? English is not my native language. I didn't understand what you asked on this comment, sorry.

Comment: I thin @guy answered my doubt.

Comment: @guy: Could you explain why it does not uniformly converge on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @matgaio However, you do have uniform convergence on any finite interval $[-A,A]$.

Comment: Yes, this is why I was asking about the interval of definition of the sequence.

Comment: @student The inequality in his post cannot hold for *all* $x\in\Bbb R$. In order to converge uniformly, you would need $|2xn-1|\le n^2\epsilon$  to hold for all $x$.

Comment: @matgaio I'm sorry. I meant to direct my comments to student.

Comment: @matgaio: I understand now. Would you mind taking a look at my edit to see if I've shown uniform convergence for the interval $[-5, 5]$?

Comment: Yes, the argument is right, because now you cannot take $x$ that freely, then $n$ large enough control the growing of $|\frac{10n}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}|$

Comment: @matgaio: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

consider $g_n(x)=x/n$ on whole $\mathbb{R}$, then $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x/n=0$, now fix $\epsilon>0$ $|x/n-0|=|x/n|<\epsilon$ whenever $n>x/\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$ $n$ depends on both $x$ and $\epsilon$ so $g_n(x)$ is not Uniformly Convergent Over $\mathbb{R}$ by the definition of Uniform Convergence. I hope from This Hint you can do your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to do it without the Wierstrass M-test.

Comment: This is why I asked if the sequence was defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I have edited my answer.thank you David.